# Rewrite cos/sin with constant

Tags: functions

Why can $\left(\frac1{a}\right)\cos(ax)$ be rewritten as $\left(\frac1{a}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ if you set x as $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ ?

Comment: Just make a typo as the book did !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici but like for real, it is a typo right? I was like wtf...

Comment: Why do you think that the "a" can be omitted in the case $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Peter think the book forgot to add that a can only be ∈ R

Comment: I rather think that the book just forgot the "a", a simple typo.

Comment: Just an FYI, the question currently has several votes to close. Next time, try adding a bit more context: "I was reading XYZ book, and this statement [statement here] appears. I tried to verify it but I seem to get [differing statement] instead" that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=\frac\pi2$, then $$\left(\frac1a\right)\cos(ax) = \left(\frac1a\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi2 a\right),$$

which is **not** the same as

$$\left(\frac1a\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right) = 0$$
so the book is missing one $a$.